# Polymorphism, Overloading and Overriding in Java with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism, processing

First of all, I'm sorry for possibly having an incorrect title, I might be thinking of something else but here goes. I have a simple program that is drawing out stars and circles in Java using the Processing applet. I have an ArrayList of type Shape.

```
ArrayList<Shape> shapeList= new ArrayList<Shape>();
```

I then add various stars and circles through a constructor which uses overloading to determine whether its a star or a circle.

For the star:

```
shapeList.add( new Shape(x, y, size, colour, numPoints, pApp));
```

For the circle:

```
shapeList.add( new Shape(x, y, size, colour, pApp));
```

Once that is done, the task is to loop round the ArrayList to draw and render the shapes. The star and circle class both have their own draw methods to draw the shapes.

```
    for ( Shape shape: shapeList )
    {
        shape.update();
        shape.draw();
    }
```

The problem I'm having, is that it is failing to override the empty draw() inside the Shape class when I want it to 'fall back' into the Star or Circle class and execute that specific draw() depending on whether the object is a star or circle at that point in the ArrayList.

Thanks!

Comment: But you're not instantiating a `Star` or `Circle`, you're instantiating `Shape`s... You need to use the constructors from the appropriate classes.

Comment: For Star, I advise adding a Polygon / Polygon2D. For Circle, I advise adding an Ellipse2D.

Comment: @Zircon yeah that was one mistake, thanks!

Comment: One way to solve your problem is to extend Shape to Circle, Star, etc. and implement draw() in each extended class.

Comment: Like others have said, you're probably supposed to create `Star` and `Circle` classes and then create instances of those classes and add those instances to the `ArrayList`. Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/inheritance) is a tutorial on inheritance that talks about what you need to do. Specifically, check out the part about extending classes and overriding functions.

Comment: It would help if you post the `Shape` class.

Answer (score 0):

Define a Shape interface

```
public interface Shape {

    // the methods circle and star need to implement
    void update();
    void draw();
}
```

Implement a Circle

```
public class Circle implements Shape {


    public Circle(int x, int y, int size, Color colour, App pApp){
       // your code
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing Circle");
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        System.out.println("Updating Circle");
    }
}
```

Implement a Star

```
public class Star implements Shape {


    public Circle(int x, int y, int size, int numPoints, Color colour, App pApp){
       // your code
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing Star");
    }
    @Override
    public void update() {
        System.out.println("Updating Star");
    }       

}
```

Add them to your list

```
shapeList.add( new Star(x, y, size, colour, numPoints, pApp));
shapeList.add( new Circle(x, y, size, colour, pApp));
shapeList.add( new Star(x, y, size, colour, numPoints, pApp));
shapeList.add( new Circle(x, y, size, colour, pApp));

for ( Shape shape: shapeList )
{
    shape.update();
    shape.draw();
}
```